# Access object from server response when using yield call for a blob file

Tags: reactjs, redux, blob, redux-saga

So I try to make a call to the server to get a PDF file, which works when the file exist. But when there is no file, i get a 404 response from the server. I need to access this status in the result object. The problem is when the blob tries to download and it doesnt find the file, it does not provide me with the result from server, but instead it says this:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

If I tweak it a bit it says "Error fetching file". But I really need the status from the server response due to displaying correct info if the file does not exist or if its an server error. Due to sensitive data, I cannot copy paste the result from server in here. But it does show result: { statusCode: 404 " } in the object.

This is my code:

```
export function* getInvoicePDFWorkerSaga(arg) {
  const {
    organizationNumber, agreementId, invoiceNumber,
  } = arg;
  try {
    const blob = yield call(invoices.getInvoicePDF, organizationNumber, agreementId, invoiceNumber);
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadFile(blobUrl, `invoice_${invoiceNumber}`, 'pdf');
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(actions.getInvoicePDFFailedAction(invoiceNumber, formatError(e)));
    const retry = yield call(RetryPrompt);
    if (retry) {
      yield call(getInvoicePDFWorkerSaga, arg);
    }
  }
}


getInvoicePDF: (organizationNumber, agreementId, invoiceNumber) => (
    getBlob({ url: ENDPOINTS.getInvoicePDF(organizationNumber, agreementId, invoiceNumber) })
  ),
```

Comment: Use console.log and show us what exactly is `blob`

Comment: @kinduser Its an object containing "Error: Error fetching file"

Comment: Consider showing us the `invoices.getInvoicePDF` function

Comment: @kinduser updated now. But as u can see its a getBlob which ofc makes it only attach the file. But thats needed when its gonna download the file directly? That probably makes the issue of no result object too

Comment: @kinduser I found it! It's in the getBlob method :D